# Getting Different Values for the same formula in C++ Than in C#

Tags: c#, c++, math

I have a formula from a C++ application that I have implemented in C# but I am producing vastly different results.

The Sample Latitude is:

Here is the C++ Implementation:

```
double lat = 0.959931088596881 //In Radians
double lon = -3.14159265358979 //In Radians
double alt = altitude;

double a = 6378137;
double e = 8.1819190842622e-2;

double N = a / sqrt(1.0 - (e * e) * (sin(lat) * sin(lat)));

x = (N+alt) * cos(lat) * cos(lon);
```

Final result for X: -3.66659e+006

Here is the C# Implementation:

```
double lat = this.DegreesToRadians(latitude);
double lon = this.DegreesToRadians(longitude);
double alt = altitude;
double a = 6378137;
double e = 8.1819190842622e-2;
double N = a / Math.Sqrt(1.0 - (e * e) * (Math.Sin(lat) * Math.Sin(lat)));

x = (N + alt) * Math.Cos(lat) * Math.Cos(lon);
```

Final result for X: -3666593.52237417

I am sure there must be something simple I am missing. I have tried pulling out different pieces and parts but can't quite figure out where the difference is occurring.

Comment: Looks pretty much the same to me.

Comment: The results are identical (up to precise of C++ solution), just the print showed them differently.

Comment: That little `e` in the first output is very important!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I have a formula from a C++ application that I have implemented in C# but I am producing vastly different results.

Nope, you're getting very, very similar results - with different representations.

- C++: -3.66659e+006
- C#: -3666593.52237417

Those are the same number (to 6 significant digits) - the C++ representation is just using scientific representation.

Here's a piece of C# to demonstrate the same value shown in two ways:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Source code using scientific representation
        double value = -3.66659e+006;
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("G")); // General representation
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("E")); // Scientific representation
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-3666590
-3.666590E+006
```

Now we can't tell what the C++ result is beyond the first 6 significant digits, based just on your output, although you can probably use `printf` to show you more details. But the values are at least *very similar*.